# Random BSOD ntoskrnl.exe (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash, bsod, ntoskrnl.exe

I get BSOD at random times and have been for a while now on my Windows 7 machine. It is really new, and I already tried wiping the graphic card drivers and installing them again (making sure that they are *of course* up to date).

I get a variety of bug check strings on a few different drivers. The single file that is in all of my BSODs is ntoskrnl.exe

**Bug Check Strings**
- `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION`
- `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`
- `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`
- `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`
- `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`

I would rather not resort to getting a completely new PC, as I have already thrown a lot of money on my current one.

[Here is a .zip file with my dumps](http://ge.tt/7Hbmgzv/v/0?c).

Comment: Looks like your RAM has going bad. Have you tested it?

Comment: How is the heat in your case? Are you getting the actuall BSOD or just a black screen? What drivers have been updated recently?

Comment: This was happening to me with a Gigabyte Z87 UD5H motherboard. A BIOS upgrade completely fixed the issues.

Comment: @Moses I tested it for 2 hours today with memtest86+, no errors.

Comment: @Scott I get a stable about 40c on 100% load

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Hmm, I might have to do that I have a Gigabyte mobo as well (870A-UD3)